# Explicit specialization of template variable

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, linker-errors, explicit-specialization

Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47972746/8360627) about explicit specialisation of static const class members of a template class, and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47544299/8360627) about explicit specialisation of a template class, but my issue is with explicit specialisation of a variable template.

My MCVE:

```cpp
//my_templated_literal.h
#pragma once

template <typename T>
constexpr T val;
```

```
//my_specialised_literal.h
#pragma once

#include "my_templated_literal.h"

template <>
constexpr int val<int> = 2;
```

```cpp
//my_specialised_literal.cc
#include "my_specialised_literal.h"
```

```
//main.cc
#include "my_specialised_literal.h"

int main() {}
```

Compile command: `$CXX -std=c++14 my_specialised_literal.cc main.cc`
This compiles and seems to work as expected on just about every compiler version I've tried, but gives linker errors with clang-9:

> /tmp/main-ec49c7.o:(.rodata+0x0): multiple definition of `val'
>
> /tmp/my_specialised_literal-521691.o:(.rodata+0x0): first defined here

Is this an ODR violation silently accepted by most compiler versions, or is clang-9 wrong in some way? If the former, I know that if I could use C++17 I could fix it by making the specialisation `inline`, but what is a C++14 fix for the problem?

Comment: I think that your `constexpr` variable should be `static`. Other possible alternatives: (1) function, (2) static constant or (3) `enum` values.

Comment: @Phil1970 `static` was the first thing I tried, which works with clang, but gcc give compile error: `explicit template specialization cannot have a storage class`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I've worked this out:

> Is this an ODR violation silently accepted by most compiler versions?

From my understanding, yes. According to the [storage class specifiers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration) cppreference page, the template variable should have external linkage, even though it's `constexpr`, which means having multiple definitions in a translation unit is an ODR violation. According to the [defect report](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p1359r0.html#2387) linked at the bottom of that page, "current implementations appear to give internal linkage to specializations of const-qualified variable templates", which was deemed by the standards committee to not be the behaviour they intend.

> What is a C++14 fix for the problem?

It seems there isn't one.